# Trying to fade in a UIView without success

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview

I am trying to fade in a UIView as a subview of my main view. The UIView I am trying to fade in has the dimensions of 320x55.

I setup the view and a timer;

```
secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 361, 320, 55);
secondView.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:secondView];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(fadeView) userInfo:NO repeats:NO];
```

The timer triggers the following code;

```
secondView.alpha = 1.0;
CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation;
fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeInAnimation.duration = 1.5;
fadeInAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
[fadeInAnimation setDelegate:self];
[secondView.layer addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

My secondView is connected in Interface Builder and responds to other messages but I can't see anything happening on screen.

Can anyone please help me figure out what's going on here?

Thanks,
Ricky.

---

In reply to a following recommendation:

I'm a bit unsure here. Initially I put this code in (because I see secondView as an instance of UIView?):

```
[secondView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[secondView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
[secondView setAlpha:1.0]; 
[secondView commitAnimations];
```

I then tried your suggestion which didn't produce warnings or errors, but it still does brings nothing to the surface:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
[secondView setAlpha:1.0]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks! Ricky.

---

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should be able to do this a bit simpler. Have you tried something like this?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[secondView setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: That code produces 3 warnings, all saying that UIView may not respond to the messages. It also crashes the app. Why is this?

Comment: @Ricky: That's odd. Are you using the iPhone SDK?

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code? It compiles just fine when I do it.

Comment: Yes I'm using the iPhone SDK. See my edited original post for the formatted code.

Comment: Produces no warnings for me. Maybe your secondView was not a UIView?

Answer (score 16):

it seems to me that one thing you're missing is that your view may already have an alpha of 1.0.  make sure the alpha is 0 (or whatever you desire it to be) prior to the animation call.

i prefer to use block animations for this.  it's cleaner and more self-contained.

```
secondView.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^() {
    secondView.alpha = 1.0f;
}];
```

Comment: To be specific about animation's own thread, it is the main thread. The animation changes dispatched over time interval (animation duration). And a side note, always remember to call "UIView animateWithDur..." methods from main thread. Therefore  if this call made from a thread other than main, wrap it with dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[UIView animateWithDur...]});

Comment: +1 for `your view may already have an alpha of 1.0`. In that case, "animating" from 1.0 to 1.0, the animation ends immediately and not after the specified duration. Make sure there is actually a change to animate.

Comment: @GökhanBarışAker correct on the point about threading.  most of my blocks are on their own thread and i spoke too soon.  i've updated the post.  thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 11):

This won't answer your question if you insist on using CoreAnimations, but for iPhoneOS it's much easier to use animation blocks for UIView animations.

```
secondView.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInSecondView" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
secondView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

Also, you can invoke a delegate in delayed time with

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: You can get rid of the timer alltogether by also calling UIView setAnimationDelay. e.g. [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5]

Answer (score 8):

Here is also a good alternative with many options and easy to use.

```
  [secondViewController.view setAlpha:0.0];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
          delay:0.0 
          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn // See other options
          animations:^{
            [secondViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Completion Block
        }];
```